How do I modulate the output power of a laser diode at 1 kHz?
I am planning to use L785P5 laser diode from Thorlabs, which has a maximum output power of 5 mW. As per my requirement, I need power output in the range of 0-100 µW. So how do I go about reducing the output power? Also, the frequency of laser modulation is 1 kHz.

This laser diode is a 5 mW ... I think you can't change the power. So an optical system "should" be used.

@Antonio51 It's just the diode, it doesn't include any driver circuitry, so the output power is easily modulated by varying the current. (Unlike some pre-build diode modules.)

A diode may stop lasing below some threshold current, there's a limit to how far you can turn it down.

Please link a readable data sheet that doesn't require a log-in.

Seems like you need an optical attenuator at the laser's output port.

@Antonio51 That link is the same as in the OP. It's generated on the fly by the CMS system of thorlabs, and does not work.

@Andyaka This should be the correct one. https://www.thorlabs.com/_sd.cfm?fileName=QTN007821-S01.pdf&partNumber=L785P5

@MrGerber ok. I set first the link in OP question ... but this was not complete ... And I could not modify it.

I've taken this graph from the specification sheet linked to on this page and added the green box: -

The green box represents where the laser actually produces a laser light output. Point to note: the light output minimum is about 0.5 mW and if you try and go below this you may disrupt the laser's effectiveness and incur a delay before it starts producing laser light again.

As per my requirement, I need power output in the range of 0-100 uW

Not with this laser. It's usable range is 0.5 mW to 5 mW typically and far too high for what you want without some kind of optical attenuator.

Thorlabs product page for L785P5


How do I modulate the output power of a laser diode at 1 kHz?

Regarding the modulation method, at 1 kHz this is trivial. Set up a resistor to bias the laser diode at 18 mA (as per the graph above where 18 mA is equivalent to 2.5 mW output power). This is easily achieved with an op-amp and BJT plus a few resistors.
Then modulate the level of the current produced by the op-amp and BJT. There are plenty of circuits that can do this at 1 kHz all the way up to 100 kHz: -

Image from Understanding the basics of laser diode drivers.

Possibly relevant, the Thorlabs neutral density filter page, specifically the 15 dB (3% transmission) filter: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=5011

It's very un-intuitive that the leftmost curve is on the right axis and vice versa. Took me a few seconds to interpret that correctly! It might be worth to note that the curve given is skewed towards the low end of the typical Threshold current variation room - given in the second table, as Min 10mA, Typ 20mA and Max 25mA.

@MrGerber a good attempt to find where the data sheet is but to no avail tomorrow. It looks like Thorlabs adjust the addresses every day in order to prevent this. Today and now your proposed link works. This morning mine did. Yesterday the accepted link worked but didn't this morning so, I'm abandoning your edit.

@Andyaka Sure - it's your post, your desicion. But the one i posted is not a generated link, but the link /to the generator/. Look at the contents of the URL, they are static in nature. The one already in your post and in OP's contains a hash, inherently a non-static content.

@MrGerber you might be right - maybe add it as a comment to see if it works tomorrow.

@Andyaka Willing to put money on it! ;) I posted it in the comments of the question as well.

I'm not a betting man but I'd say the link you provided is exactly the same link as the one for the spec sheet on the Thorlabs product page. That's where I got this morning's spec sheet link from and that died later today so, I have my doubts LOL

@Andyaka Seems like my link works today as well!

You should drive the diode with a variable current source circuit.
The laser has a monitor diode mounted to the back side of the emitter in order to monitor output power.
You can connect the monitor diode to a transimpedance amplifier and use that in a control loop to adjust the diode current to get the correct output power.
Alternately, if you don't need high accuracy you can try to calibrate the output vs. current and drive the diode open loop, i.e. without using the monitor diode.  It will vary a lot part-to-part, with temperature and age of the diode, so it's typically not recommended.
Note that diode lasers can be noisier when run at output power much lower than rated.
EDIT: As Andy AKA rightly points out, this diode may not be able to put out such low power, so you will need to use an optical attenuator on the output.

Thanks for your EDIT.
